# Actualizar DataGridView al ejecutar consulta

Tags: c#, datagridview

tengo un dataGridView que me muestra los valores de una consulta, y  un botón que al clickar suma un valor entrado en un textbox a todos los registros de la tabla, esto funciona bien, lo que no logro es actualizar automáticamente el dataGridView, he probado con refresh, con update , cambiando el datasource y no hay manera...

Codigo del button:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BindingSource odades = new BindingSource();
        conexio con = new conexio();
        con.connString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-0T0VKC8\SQLSAGE50_5;Initial Catalog=2019MC;Integrated Security=True";
        int valor = Convert.ToInt32(text1.Text);
        string query = "UPDATE descuen set pvp = pvp + " + valor + " ";
        con.Origen(odades, query, true);
        dgv1.Refresh();

    }
```

El bool que le paso a con.Origen, solo le indica al método si es una operación o solo una select para retornarme el datasource.
(No es la mejor manera, es evidente, pero he probado infinidad de maneras y no me resulta ninguna).

Codigo de la Clase:

```
class conexio
{
      private BindingSource _origen;
    public BindingSource oDades
    {
        get { return _origen; }
        set
        {
            _origen = value;


        }
    }
    private string _connString;
    public string connString
    {
        get { return _connString; }
        set
        {
            _connString = value;
        }
    }
    public  void Origen(BindingSource odades, string query, bool op )
    {

        using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(_connString))
        {
            sql.Open();
            if (op)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sql))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                    }
                  }

            }
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select articulo,pvp from descuen", sql))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                odades.DataSource = dt;
            }

        }
        _origen = odades;
    }
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Ubica en este sector el código resaltado:

```
      using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select articulo,pvp from descuen", sql)) {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        odades.DataSource = dt;
        **odades.Update();
        **odades.Refresh();
      }
```

Al recargar y actualizar el dt de tu DGV se debe agregar la actualización posterior para que el refresco sea de forma automática.

Ante cualquier duda, consulta.

Comment: He añadido el .Update tal y como me recomiendas, pero sigue sin funcionar. El DGV se queda tal cual.

Comment: Consulta, de casualidad tu web es sincrónica o asincrónica?

Comment: No web, es un windows forms.

Comment: Gran detalle amigo, mira voy a darle una vuelta unos minutos a tu código y te respondo.